# The session of the bot with an existing user

Tags: c#, botframework

I am looking for a way to bind the session of the bot with an existing user, please tell me how to implement it

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new conversation, you need the user's `name` and `id`. That implies that your chatbot has previously conversed with that person and has saved their name/id for later use. Here's the example from the [Bot Framework documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-connector#start-a-conversation) on how to start a new conversation:

```
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "Larry", id: "@UV357341");
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(actvity.ServiceUrl));
var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);

IMessageActivity message =  Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
message.Text = "Hello, Larry!";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```